# Installing component in dclusr.dpk breakes other components

Tags: delphi, custom-component, delphi-6

First I've installed [RX library 2.75](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rxlib/) and some others.
Then I'm trying to install custom (not mine) component `TMyLookupEdit` which is derived from `TRxLookupEdit`.
I do it thru *main menu* -> *Component* -> *Install Component...* and choose components' *.pas* file

And when Delphi tries to rebuild dclusr.dpk I get something like this (don't remember, to reproduce it I've found no other way but to reinstall Delphi):

```
Can't load package c:\program files\borland\delphi6\Projects\Bpl\dclrx6.bpl.
Cannot load package 'RxCtl6.'  It contains unit 'FileUtil,'which is also contained in package 'RxCtl660'
```

Then IDE tells me that `MyLookupEdit` component is installed **and** about 100 other components are **un**installed. All RX components are gone from palette

I'm sure I've installed only RxCtl6 and not RxCtl6**60**. But they are both in *C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\Bpl* now. The only clue I have is that #define in dclusr.dpk file (see below)

How can I make RX and this component work together ?

---

Here is my dclusr.dpk (most #defines are omitted):

```
{$LIBSUFFIX '60'}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  designide,
  vcldb,
  dbrtl,
  vclx,
  VclSmp,
  RxCtl6,
  RxDB6;

contains
  RegGrid in '..\..\..\..\_work\Delphi\__Install\__Components\No-package components\RegGrid\RegGrid.pas',
  Tabenter in '..\..\..\..\_work\Delphi\__Install\__Components\No-package components\TABENTER.PAS',
  MyLE in '..\..\..\..\_work\Delphi\__Install\__Components\No-package components\MyLookupEdit\MyLE.pas';

end.
```

---

**Solution**

1. Remove {$LIBSUFFIX '60'} from dclusr.dpk
2. Delete dclusr60.bpl file
3. Rebuild dclusr.dpk

Many thanks to Serg for directions!

Comment: b.t.w this `MyLookupEdit` component looks pretty useless, so the solution could be just to rewrite projects to not use it. But it was introduced to our projects about 7-8 years ago and I'm maintaining them only for 6 months, so I'm not sure what impact will be

Comment: Maybe I should include this component in RX package, RxLookup unit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm sure I've installed only RxCtl6
>   and not RxCtl660. But they are both in
>   C:\Program
>   Files\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\Bpl

The coexistence of RxCtl6.bpl and RxCtl660.bpl means that your RxCtl6 package was somehow compiled with and without {$LIBSUFFIX '60'} directive.

I had the similar problem after installing an updated TeeChart component package, with the result that TeeChart - dependent packages became unworkable.
As a quick solution you can try to replace RxCtl6 and RxDB6 by RxCtl660 and RxDB660 in the "required" section. Also check your RX *.dpk sources for {$LIBSUFFIX '60'} directive - an actual the problem is connected to {$LIBSUFFIX '60'} directive.

Don't reinstall Delphi if some packages disappear - Delphi keeps the information about the installed packages in registry, so

- try to fix the problem in IDE; if it does not help
- try to fix the problem in registry

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's such a relief to here someone else encountered it! Replacing 6 with 660 files doesn't work. It says "Required package 'RxCtl660' not found". Tomorrow I will try to get rid of 660 files and registry entries, disable {$LIBSUFFIX} in dclusr.dpk and reinstall this small component. I will report my progress here